# Converting PDF with Arabic Text to Images on Linux

Tags: linux, image, pdf, image-processing, imagemagick

I am trying to convert the pages of a PDF document to images files on Linux machine. I am using Imagemagick and it works perfectly for English PDF’s, such as this one:

http://arbsq.net/dev/test_en.pdf

But for Arabic, for the following file http://arbsq.net/dev/test_pdf_ar_small.pdf (which you can see clearly is not damaged), when I run the convert command, it gives this error message:

```
-bash-3.2$ convert test_pdf_ar_small.pdf[1] small-1.jpg
```

> **** Warning:  An error occurred while reading an XREF table.
>
>   *** The file has been damaged.  This may have been caused    *** by a problem while converting or transfering the file.    ****
>   Ghostscript will attempt to recover the data. ERROR: /undefined in
>   /BXlevel Operand stack:    65   0   1   --dict:6/6(ro)(G)--   obj
>   Execution stack:    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--
>   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3
>   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
>   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--
>   Dictionary stack:    --dict:1129/1686(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--
>   --dict:107/200(L)--   --dict:107/200(L)--   --dict:104/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:241/347(ro)(G)--   --dict:18/24(L)-- Current allocation mode is local ESP Ghostscript 815.02: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
>   convert: Postscript delegate failed `test_pdf_ar_small.pdf'. convert:
>   missing an image filename`small-1.jpg'.

And I tried to open the PDF using ghostscript and it seems to give the same error:

```
-bash-3.2$ gs test_pdf_ar_small.pdf
```

> ESP Ghostscript 815.02 (2006-04-19) Copyright (C) 2004 artofcode LLC,
>   Benicia, CA.  All rights reserved. This software comes with NO
>   WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.    **** Warning:  An error
>   occurred while reading an XREF table.    *** The file has been
>   damaged.  This may have been caused    *** by a problem while
>   converting or transfering the file.    **** Ghostscript will attempt
>   to recover the data. ERROR: /undefined in /BXlevel Operand stack:
>   65   0   1   --dict:6/6(ro)(G)--   obj Execution stack:
>   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
>   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop
>   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval-- Dictionary stack:    --dict:1117/1686(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:107/200(L)--   --dict:107/200(L)--   --dict:104/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:241/347(ro)(G)--   --dict:18/24(L)-- Current allocation mode is local ESP Ghostscript 815.02: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

And I tried to use image magic from Perl but didn’t work with the same error.

However, when I tried to use ghostscript on windows, it was able to open the file, though with some warnings. So the problem would be opening these PDFs on Linux.

Is there any way to handle these errors, or an alternative way to extract images from PDF?

Comment: I looked for it but I don't see where to download, and how to install on linux (I have guest (non-root) access)

Comment: I've just try your file: `pdftoppm test_pdf_ar_small.pdf arabic -png` gave me a set of png images with text. You can install it into your home directory (if it don't mounted with `noexec`). BTW, I've tried imagemagic too, and it works!

Comment: @hmghaly: if possible, update your ghostscript; mine `gs --version 9.05` works fine with your test file.

Comment: **An error occurred while reading an XREF table.** Your PDF *test_pdf_ar_small.pdf* uses cross reference streams instead of cross reference tables. Cross reference streams have been introduced in PDF 1.5. Your Ghostscript version is pretty ancient. Thus, I assume it does not support cross reference streams yet.

Comment: @barti_ddu It works! but how can I extaract the images using ghostscript, can you provide this as an answer?

Comment: @hmghaly: if you've updated ghostscript, your imagemagick `convert` command should utilize it automatically; just try it out :)

Comment: @barti_ddu I am not able to update it, it just works when I specify the gs version, but since the imagemagick is using the old version, the problem is the same, so how can I include the gs version in the imagemagick convert command?

Comment: @hmghaly: and 'pure' gs command will look like `gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=test%d.jpg -dJPEGQ=100 -r300x300 -q test_pdf_ar_small.pdf -c quit`; adjust it to your needs, but try imagemagick first.

Comment: It seems to be working without an error but I cannot find the output file :) Anyway I will try to find a way to update the imagemagick to use the new version of gs, or to include this new version in the convert command somehow, anyway please sumbit an answer so that I can accept it, you've given me already alot of help :)

Comment: it repeats the error message:
| ../pcl/pcfontpg.c:104: pcl_print_font_page(): printer reset failied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to update your *ghostscript* first and somehow tell *imagemagick* to utilize it (either by tuning the *$PATH* or *delegate.xml*).

However, you can also utilize the *ghostscript* directly, here is an example to start with:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 \
    -sOutputFile=out%d.jpg \
    -dJPEGQ=100 -r300x300 -q \
    test_pdf_ar_small.pdf -c quit
```

Note the `-sOutputFile` option, which is a template for output file names (where `%d` is integer range from `FirstPage` to `LastPage`), so in the example above the single output file will be called `out1.jpg`.

Credits go to @mkl for better gs error explanation.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you but I it seems that the gs command does not produce any output 
gs --version 9.05 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=koromba%d.jpg -dJPEGQ=100 -r300x300 -q test_pdf_ar_small.pdf -c quit
I do not get an error message, but only this:
8.15.2
And when I search for the output file, I cannot find it anywhere:
-bash-3.2$ find -name 'koromba'
-bash-3.2$
How do you think we can debug this?

Comment: @hmghaly: do you enter the command _literally_ as you've typed? `gs --version x y z` will just print gs version (currently installed) and ignore any other options. You have to upgrade gs to at least version 9 for pdf 1.5 handling.

Comment: ah so that's why :) but I actually have non-root access so I am unable to do the upgrade ! So it was not working after all and the abcense of error was because the command only displays the version ... do you have any idea how to update the gs with non-root access?

Comment: @hmghaly: no easy way. Somehow i've missed that you're still on old version. I will delete my answer in a few minutes, may be someone will come up with solution that suites you. Btw, is using an online conversion service (like http://www.zamzar.com) an option?

Comment: :( Well, no problem, and thanks for suggesting an online service, maybe I will try it if eveything else fails

Comment: @hmghaly: hmm, it seems there is no way to delete an accepted answer. Feel free to unaccept it ;)

Comment: no problem, appreciate your help anyway, at least you pointed me towards the "hopefully" right direction for this version thing

Comment: @hmghaly: samara university has statically linked binary gs distributions here: http://uni-smr.ac.ru/archive/linux/science/Ghostscript/binaries/ which you can try as a last resort.

Comment: Thank you. This looks promising, I just have a question (sorry I'm still a newbie in Linux :) ). After downloading and uncompressing the tgz file, I see there is the file pcl6-905-linux_x86 which I think is the file I should use, but I cannot execute it. Can you help me know how to use it?

Comment: `wget http://uni-smr.ac.ru/archive/linux/science/Ghostscript/binaries/ghostscript-9.05-linux_x86.tgz`, then `tar -zxvf ghostscript-9.05-linux_x86.tgz`, then `cd ghostscript-9.05-linux_x86` and finally `./gs-905-linux_x86 your options here`.

Comment: Again sorry to bother you, this distribution seems to work to some extent, but it does not recognized the switches -c and -q, (it tells me "unrecgnized switch" and when I remove them it gives a garbage output.

Which of these options should I use?
Options: -dNOPAUSE -E[#] -h -L<PCL|PCLXL> -K<maxK> -l<PCL5C|PCL5E|RTL> -Z...
         -sDEVICE=<dev> -g<W>x<H> -r<X>[x<Y>] -d{First|Last}Page=<#>
         -sOutputFile=<file> (-s<option>=<string> | -d<option>[=<value>])*
         -J<PJL commands>

Comment: Enter _literally_ (for your test file): `./gs-905-linux_x86 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=out%d.jpg -dJPEGQ=100 -r300x300 -q test_pdf_ar_small.pdf -c quit` ; i.e. the same options like in the answer except use `./gs-905-linux_x86` instead of `gs` for the binary. It works for me (tested on amd64 machine without 32-bit gs libs).